# Error when using 'omit' feature in Test Unit 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I'm a bit stumped by my issue. I am using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.2. I am attempting to using the 'omit' feature in Test Unit 2.3.0. Here is my test:

```
def test_create_reward_program
  omit("Pending")

  reward_program = RewardProgram.find_by_program_name("test_foo")
  assert_equal "test_foo", reward_program.program_name

end
```

When I run 'rake test', I get the following:

```
1) Error:
test_create_reward_program(AwardControllerTest):
Test::Unit::OmittedError: Pending
    /test/functional/award_controller_test.rb:43:in `test_create_reward_program'


148 tests, 261 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
```

0% passed

I don't know why it's marking it as 'error' when it should mark it as 'omission'. Anyone know?

I also noticed that this does work:

```
def test_create_reward_program
  omit "Pending" do
    reward_program = RewardProgram.find_by_program_name("test_foo")
    assert_equal "test_foo", reward_program.program_name
  end        
end
```

All the tutorials and examples I have found indicates that my first example should work.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this one?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code for Test::Unit 2.3.0, that is precisely the coded behaviour. It throws unless given a block.

The [documentation](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCaseOmissionSupport.html#method-i-omit) lists the source for `omit` as:

```
# File lib/test/unit/omission.rb, line 77
def omit(message=nil, &block)
  message ||= "omitted."
  if block_given?
    omission = Omission.new(name, filter_backtrace(caller), message)
    add_omission(omission)
  else
    raise OmittedError.new(message)
  end
end
```

By the way, if you ever upgrade, Rails 3.1.0.rc1, running on Ruby 1.9.2p0, which bundles Minitest, does not define `omit` but adds `skip`. For example:

```
# test/unit/bird_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class BirdTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "creation" do
    bird = Bird.new
    assert_not_nil bird
  end

  test "not implemented" do
    skip
    assert false
  end

end
```

Using the `turn` gem to pretty-print my output, I get:

```
$ rake test:units
Started

BirdTest:
     PASS creation (0.06s) 
     SKIP not implemented (0.00s) 

Finished in 0.060828 seconds.

2 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 1 skips
```